# Attribue error when trying to train K-means model and running its predict and score functions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, k-means

I've been trying to train a K-means model on the dataset of dogs vs cats.
This is the data I've been feeding to the model using `train_df.values` train_df is my training dataframe.

```
array([[167, 171, 173, ...,   2,   2,   2],
   [ 40,  43,  46, ...,  35,  41,  35],
   [ 33,  17,  22, ..., 172, 165, 149],
   ...,
   [ 48,  52,  40, ...,  90, 171, 159],
   [253, 254, 250, ..., 121, 113, 120],
   [240, 240, 241, ..., 254, 254, 254]], dtype=uint8)
```

Here is the shape of this data :

> (25000, 22500)

Here is the model initiation and fitting itself (*train is the data above*)
**NOTE: Testing it on n_clusters bigger then 1 won't produce the error, however, the same error will still be produced in the predict and score methods when trying to predict or score with the test data**

**NOTE 2: I also know that this approach might not be correct for my case, since my data is unlabeled, I do this as learning and understanding unsupervised learning**

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, init='k-means++', random_state=42).fit(train)
```

This is the error I've been getting after running k-means or the score/predict functions of k-means.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

I checked if there are nulls in my data, and my data is free from null values, and unfortunately all the solutions that come up when I try to google it are in situations which are not similar to mine at all.

I would like to know how I can fix this so that I won't have this error again.

Comment: @Phoenix I tried doing the marked solution, it didn't help...

Comment: How do you want to cluster the data in one cluster?! there is no need for clustering in this case.

Comment: Did you try to change `n_clusters` to 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @Phoenix I did run it on 2 clusters, but as I wrote in my first note, the error will persist in the predict and score functions of K-means

Comment: @Phoenix nvm, after trying the solution you've given me, it worked, I didn't downgrade numpy properly the first time